# Delay after selecting file with the File Upload browse button

Tags: javascript, file-upload

After I click the browse button and select a file, sometimes there is a delay when the selected file appears.  Why does this happen?  Thank you.

Comment: I am referring to this question on StackOverflow:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously. I click the Run Snippet button and select a file with the browse button and sometimes there is a delay when the selected file appears.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is very unclear.  What "appears"?  Are you referring to the file name in an `<input type="file">` element?  Something else?  What does JavaScript have to do with this?  Please elaborate on the question to clarify the problem.  For tips and information on asking a good question, you are encouraged to read [ask] and its linked resources.